# What is the name of this result about isosceles triangles?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

$\Delta ABC$ is isosceles with $AB=AC=p$. $D$ is a point on $BC$ where $AD=q$, $BD=u$ and $CD=v$.

[image: isosceles triangle]

Then the following holds.

$$p^2=q^2+uv$$

I would like to know whether this result has a name.

Comment: If you have time ( still in high school or freshman) read "Geometry revisted" by coxeter. It will really help .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will check it out.

Comment: One could also name it as "trivial" ;)

Comment: @Jan Indeed, just saying "trivial" is a great way to change the subject. It's like "left as an exercise for the reader".

Comment: @Jan But why leave it as [folklore](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/116035)?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Stewart's theorem**

Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ are the length of the sides of the triangles. Let $d$ be the length of the cevian to the side of length $a$.  If the cevian divides the side of length $a$ into two segments of length $m$ and $n$ with $m$ adjacent to $c$ and $n$ adjacent to $b$, then Stewart's theorem states that 
$b^2m +c^2n=a(d^2+mn)$

*Note*

**Apollonius's theorem** is a special case of this theorem.

Comment: Actually I am just wondering if there is a more general theorem that includes the result that I posted and Apollonius's theorem. And here comes exactly what I am looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: This has the useful mnemonic $man+dad=bmb+cnc$

Comment: @Displayname Are there full (or related) names for bmb and cnc?

Comment: @Mick A man and his dad put a bomb in the sink.

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:** I forgot some factors $\frac{1}{2}$.

---

Derivation:
$$h^2 = p^2 - \frac{1}{4}(u+v)^2\ ,$$
$$q^2 = h^2 + \frac{1}{4}(u-v)^2\ ,$$
where $h$ is the height perpendicular to $BC$. Therefore,
$$p^2 = h^2 + \frac{1}{4}(u+v)^2 = q^2 - \frac{1}{4}(u-v)^2 + \frac{1}{4}(u+v)^2 = q^2 + uv\ .$$
I don't know if it has a name, but it is certainly a nice formula!

Comment: I obtained the result in exactly the same way!

Answer (score 6):

Besides Stewart's theorem, Ptolemy's theorem also gives this one as an immediate consequence:
$
\def\len#1{\overline{#1}}
\def\ang{\angle}
\def\para{\parallel}
\def\tri{\triangle}
$

Let $E$ be the reflection of $A$ about the perpendicular bisector of $CD$. Then clearly $\len{CE} = q$ and $\len{DE} = p$. Also $DE \para AB$, so $\tri ABD \equiv \tri DEA$, and hence $\len{AE} = u$. Finally $ADCE$ is cyclic, so Ptolemy's theorem gives the desired result.

Answer (score 5):

This result (with several proofs) appears in a note by L. Hoehn in [The Mathematical Gazette (March 2000 pp 71-73)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-gazette/article/8403-a-neglected-pythagoreanlike-formula/65FA46231A23EF422A4CD611700E4F45). The author suggests, plausibly, that it must have been found many times, but notes that "it doesn't seem to appear in the mathematical literature".  He does not refer to or propose any name for the result.

Answer (score 2):

It can be seen as a very straight-forward corollary of the intersecting chords theorem. If $c$ is a circle with center $A$ and passing through $B$ and $C$, $c$ has radius $p$. Then $BC$ is a chord of $c$ and line $AD$ intersect $c$ forming a diameter, say at points $E$ and $F$ (suppose $E$ is the point closer to $D$). Then $ED=p-q$ and $FD=p+q$. Your result follows from the intersecting chord theorem: $ED\cdot FD=BD\cdot CD$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $BC$. Let $MD = d$. 
It is easy to see that $v - u = 2d$ and so $v = u + 2d$.
By Pythagoras 
$$p^2- q^2 
= MC^2 - MD^2 
= (MC + MD)(MC - MD) 
= [(u + v)/2 + d][(u + v)/2 - d]
= [(2u + 2d)/2 + d] [(2u + 2d)/2 - d] 
= (u + 2d)u = vu.$$

Hence $p^2 = q^2 + uv$.

Comment: I think the relation is $u - v = 2d$

Comment: But the question asks for the *name* of the theorem. You don't mention that.